# Make class return a field

Tags: c#, class

Is there a way to make a class return one of its fields by default like that:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string something;
}

TestClass test = new TestClass();
test = "alpha"; // "alpha" string is assigned to "something"
Console.Write(test); // test returns "alpha" string from "something"
```

How to make this work?

Comment: Although this could be done to some extent, it makes your code very confusing. Others reading it will likely think "Why can a string be assigned to a `TestClass` variable? What does that even mean?". So what is `TestClass` actually? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I can run **exactly** that code in C# (some mods to the class definition) see [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0604kI) - but it does not do **exactly** what the OP is asking for ;o)

Comment: Yes, [that is possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/conversion-operators).  Doesn't mean it is a good idea to use it in a case like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For all those saying that's impossible,)**

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string something;

    public static implicit operator TestClass(string s) => new TestClass { something = s};

    public static implicit operator string(TestClass testClass) => testClass.something;
}
```

Usage:

```
TestClass test = new TestClass();
test = "alpha";
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Gives:

```
alpha
```

**Note**: `Console.WriteLine` takes `test` as `string` and calls `Console.WriteLine(string value)` overload thanks to implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make "a class return a field", but you can override its `ToString` method, so when it's printed with something like `Console.Write` you'll get the output you want:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Something {get; set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Somethig;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does overriding ToString help in assigning a value to a field?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make a class return one of its fields by default?

No. Classes are not designed to return any value.

An alternative way to achieve what you mentioned in your question is defining property with `get; set;`, something like:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Something  { get; set; }
}
```

which you can use like:

```
TestClass test = new TestClass();
test.Something = "alpha"; // "alpha" string is assigned to "something"
Console.Write(test.Something); // test returns "alpha" string from "something"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use the constructor and overload method ToString(), so you get an immutable object.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private readonly string something;

    public TestClass(string something)
    {
        this.something = something;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return something;
    }
}

TestClass test = new TestClass("alpha");
Console.Write(test);
```

Comment: How does overriding ToString help in assigning a value to a field?