# C# Make a class return its instance without a function or variable

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, single-instance

So I've been working with classes with single instances in Unity for a while and generally do this:

```
class PublicThings {
    public static PublicThings I; // instance of this class
    public int Score;
    void Start { I = GetComponent<PublicThings>(); }
}
```

Usage: `PublicThings.I.Score = 10;`

Which works pretty well. However, I've been curious as to whether or not it's possible to have the instance of the class be returned without having to type `.I` after the class.

So basically here's how it would look instead:

```
PublicThings.Score = 10;
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56823044/make-class-return-a-field) seems like it's relevent but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Is this possible? If so, how would it be done?

Comment: You can make the fields, properties and methods `static`

Comment: Are there any downsides to having everything in a class static?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the singleton pattern. Start with John Skeet's explanation https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton

Comment: The main downside to making everything in a class static is that you can't substitute anything for it, which makes it difficult for unit testing. Also, you cannot use an interface or any sort of polymorphism. In general if you are using Unity you should be injecting your dependencies, and if you need "static" you should be using `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager ` or some other singleton life cycle.

Comment: Checkout [Static Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members)

Comment: @SergeyKovalev Not sure if the Singleton Pattern solves his problem, right? Check out my answer below. He would still have to call PublicThings.instance.Score = 10; which is essentially the same thing as PublicThings.I.Score = 10; Let me knwo if I'm missing something there

Answer (score 2):

Three options to do what you are looking to do:

1. Make a static property/field with the `static` keyword in the PublicThings class
2. Make a [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) and attach it to the item that is calling it ([video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPXvoWVabPY))
3. Utilize the [Singleton Pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPKAgyp8cno) (I would suggest avoid using this method before trying the other two)

Also it's worth noting that the Singleton Pattern doesn't necessarily solve your problem. You will still have to call something like `PublicThings.instance.Score`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton pattern is the way to go.
Also, with lazy instantiation.

```
public class PublicThings
{
    private static PublicThings _instance;

    // Your private constructor
    private PublicThings() { }

    public static PublicThings Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                // Construction of instance logic here
                _instance = new PublicThings();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
        // No setter, read-only property
    }

    // Decide if Score is a read-only property or not.
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Whener the single instance of `PublicThings` is required, it will be constructed and then stored. A second access to the instance will provide the stored one.

```
[Test]
public void WithTwoAccess_ToSingleInstance_MustBeTheSame()
{
    var things1 = PublicThings.Instance;
    var things2 = PublicThings.Instance;

    Assert.AreSame(things2, things1);
    // Asserts true
}
```

If your `Score` property must be set once, just change que `Instance` property to a method (commonly called `GetInstance`) which expects the value of `Score`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not sure if the Singleton Pattern solves his problem. Check out my answer. He would still have to call PublicThings.instance.Score = 10; which is essentially the same thing as PublicThings.I.Score = 10; Let me knwo if I'm missing something here.

Comment: Singleton pattern allows certain application entities to abstract the fact that `PublicThings` is a single instance, by passing as a parameter or registering to a dependency injection container. 
Provides core-safety and delines policy separation between components and their business rules.
I mean, there would be lots of services, controllers, ... which they don't want to know if they are dealing with a single instance, and they don't need  to, neither.
Well, this comment box is a way too short scope where to discuss it.